# Search for multiple criteria in mongodb

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I want to find any documents that matches with `input search string` from fields like status, amount, created_date, _id, currency and also firstName field from Users collection, also I need to populate `senderId` and `receiverId` from matching documents.

This is my sample document

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("5a6059701766d72d8872bc75"),
    "bankId" : ObjectId("5a1ff844cb8e4b304e414d51"),
    "senderId" : ObjectId("5a16ca832bedaa6c4cb4ad97"),
    "receiverId" : ObjectId("5a1f9dc3891ee80f0bb4632e"),
    "docurl" : "",
    "isSeen" : true,
    "paidOn" : ISODate("2018-01-18T08:23:12.621Z"),
    "customFees" : [],
    "existingInvoiceUrl" : "",
    "existingInvoice" : "",
    "dueDate" : "2018-01-18",
    "subTotal" : 1000,
    "amount" : 1000,
    "bank" : "ICICI",
    "notes" : "undefined",
    "status" : "pending",
    "currency" : "EURO",
    "updated_date" : ISODate("2018-01-18T08:23:12.621Z"),
    "created_date" : ISODate("2018-01-18T00:00:00.000Z"),
    "__v" : 0,
    "isAdminRead" : true
}
```

I am looking for an efficent way to do this with single mongodb query. Please help :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try following aggregation

You can simply search your string in any criteria using `$match` with `$or`... Then you need to do [`$lookup`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/lookup/) to populate your field in desired collection... And If you want sender and receiver as an object then use [`$unwind`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/unwind/) stage at the end of the pipeline... Here for `created_date` you can use `$lte` `$gte` as well...

Firstly you need to check whether the string is valid `objectId` or not

```
var mongodb = require("mongodb"),
objectid = mongodb.BSONPure.ObjectID;
const myMatch = []

const myArray = [
  { "status": { "$regex": "your_string" }},
  { "amount": { "$regex": "your_string" }},
  { "created_date": : "your_string" },
  { "currency": { "$regex": "your_string" }},
  { "firstName": { "$regex": "your_string" }}
]

if (objectid.isValid("your_string")) {
    myArray.push({ "_id": : mongoose.Types.ObjectId("your_string") })
}
```

If you have **mongodb version 3.6**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "$or": myArray } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Sender.collection.name,
    "let": { "senderId": "$senderId" },
    "pipeline": [
       { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$senderId" ] } } }
     ],
     "as": "sender"
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Receiver.collection.name,
    "let": { "receiverId": "$receiverId" },
    "pipeline": [
       { "$match": { "$expr": { "$eq": [ "$_id", "$$receiverId" ] } } }
     ],
     "as": "receiver"
  }}
 ])
```

and If you have **mongodb version** prior to **3.6**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  { "$match": { "$or": myArray } },
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Sender.collection.name,
    "localField": "senderId",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "sender"
  }},
  { "$lookup": {
    "from": Receiver.collection.name,
    "localField": "receiverId",
    "foreignField": "_id",
    "as": "receiver"
  }}
 ])
```

Comment: I am getting this Error: Uncaught error: Argument passed in must be a single String of 12 bytes or a string of 24 hex characters at new ObjectID

passed search-string = "pending"